# 'systemfit' package and systems of non-linear equations/regression

Tags: r, econometrics, nonlinear-regression

I am trying to estimate a system of non-linear equations using 'systemfit' package in R. I have had issues with it.

The two equations share the same parameters i.e. "sigma", "al" and "ae". I expect them to take the same values across the two equations. By theory, I expect 'sigma's to be the same. Though, I am getting different values for the coefficients.

I am aware that 'systemfit' allows you to impose linear restrictions on coefficients, but it seems impossible to do this with 'nlsystemfit'.

```
gammae=exp(-0.7) 
gamma0=exp(-0.7) 
#beta=0.6 
quale=q*e 

mod1=lsesv ~ log(gammae)+((sigma-1)/sigma)*(ae*trend1620-0.6*al*trend1620+log(quale)-0.6*log(labour)-(0.4)*log(kapital)) 
mod2=loutput~log(gamma0)+(sigma/(sigma-1))*log(((exp(al*trend1620)*labour^0.6)*(kapital^(0.4)))^((sigma-1)/sigma)+gammae*((exp(ae*trend1620)*quale)^((sigma-1)/sigma))) 
eqSys=list(mod1,mod2) 

start.values=c(ae=0.0016,al=0.0016, sigma=0.1) 
model.ols=nlsystemfit("OLS",eqSys,start.values,data=uk,maxiter=1000)
```

## Estimated coefficients

```
>model.ols$b*1
            ae         al      sigma 
    0.01647120 0.04431699 0.50860670 
>model.ols$b*2
        ae         al      sigma 
     0.03294239 0.08863398 1.01721341
```

In the above result, the coefficient estimates of equation 1 are half those of equation 2. I was wondering if there is any procedure that allows me to equate the respective coefficeint estimates via restrictions or alternative procedures.

Thank you,
mrrox